# Avoid copying complex data in class constructor

Tags: c++, oop, reference

Lets say I have a class, and one of the member variables is another complex class. I want to avoid creating the copy of this complex class, I just want to use it in my class. So whats the best way to organize MyClass?

At the moment I have something like this:

```
class MyClass  
{
public:
    MyClass(const ComplexClass& complex_class)
    : m_class(complex_class) {}

private:
     const ComplexClass& m_class;  // What is the best practice here?
};
```

Can I do this? Or maybe m_class should a pointer? Or what would you do in this situation?

Comment: I'd write the constructor as `explicit MyClass(const ComplexClass* p) : m_class(*p) {}` to avoid nasty surprises.

Comment: @Kerrek SB what kind of surprises?

Comment: You can certainly do this provided that the passed-in reference remains in scope, and nothing destroys the referenced object until the class no longer needs it. But if there is no contract that guarantees that the reference will remain valid, the object must be copied.

Comment: This is way too broad. Resource management in C++ is a large topic, there's no way it can be explained in one SO answer (or ten).

Comment: @AlexShirokov: Like dangling references and inadvertent implicit conversions...

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that passed reference is valid during object lifetime this solution is good enough.

If not I would recommend using some smart pointer e.g. shared_ptr that will extend the lifetime of passed data.

(Note you not only have to reorganize your class but also the declaration of `complex_class` object)

Answer (score 0):

The initialization list will allow only initialization, so the syntax `:m_class(complex_class)` will not work. The initialization list will call the constructor and not copy constructor. So I am not sure if suggested code will compile.

You can choose to initialize the member variable, by taking the input which will be taken by the constructor of the `m_class`. The const usage helps with the value of the member variable not changed during the lifecycle of the object, but the copies of the object can always be made and that can be expensive. If the intent is to avoid expensive copies, then you want to make the copy constructor and assignment operator as private.